# expected String to be a Hash: properties SHOPIFY

Tags: html, json, shopify

trying to add a custom text box field for customers to write text on product in Shopify

Keep getting this error message when trying to add the item to cart

expected String to be a Hash: properties

can someone help please

this is the code i have entered

```
    <div> 
      <label for="custom-name">Your Name</label>
      
      <input type="text" id="custom-name" form="{{product_form_id}}" name="properties"[Your Name] />
    
    </div>
```

Comment: `Keep getting this error message`. Please do specify what the error is when creating a question.

Comment: Hi, error is - expected String to be a Hash: properties

 when I try to add an item to cart when I write something in the text box field I created

Answer (score 0):

Close quotation mark after the bracket – `<input type="text" id="custom-name" form="{{product_form_id}}" name="properties[Your Name]" />`

Comment: hi thanks for your comment, I done this also and it hasnt changed anything, any other ideas? thanks